# Confused as to how caching is designed

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm looking at the orchard cms source code, specifically in the /src/orchard/caching folder.

Can someone give me a high level explanation of the architecture?

There are so many classes here which I can't get my head around.

acquirecontext, cachemodule signal, weak, defaultasynchtokenprovider, etc.

Comment: Might the Orchard forums be a better place to ask as it is such a localized question? http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: I dont see why this has close votes here? There are tons of questions on drupal, wordpress etc, why not orchard?

Answer (score 5):

The idea here is just to wrap the ASP.NET cache under an API that is aware of Orchard specificity such as multi-tenancy: both cache items and signals that could invalidate them need to be at the tenant level while keeping the API transparently oblivious to these details.
I wrote a short post a while ago to show how to use it: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/02/16/caching-items-in-orchard.aspx